# Reference anchor inside a td on click of this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

here is what i have:

```
<td class="player"><a class="link" data-display="0" data-id="1" data-workdir="4">Image.jpg</a></td>
```

Ok, and here is my jQuery:

```
$(".player").click(function(){
alert($(this + " a.link").attr("data-display"));
// Código para llamar al reproductor indicado
$.post(
    "php/player.php",
    { display : $(this).attr("data-display"), id : $(this).attr("data-id"), workdir : $(this).attr("data-id") },
    function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

});

What i'm trying to do is to pass the attributes that are inside the anchor when a person clicks the td, it would be also great to do the same when the person clicks the tr outside the td, but the td will do.
(The alert is just an experiment to see if i can reference the inside link, but it didn't work). I also know that i can put the attributes inside the td and make my life easier, but i would also like to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get it right, this is what you need:

`alert($("a.link", this).attr("data-display"));`

Comment: @Andres - Keep in mind this is both less efficient, and to many, less readable...not sure where the trend started on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get a descendant element (or [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) as well, in this case), like this:

```
$(this).find("a.link").attr("data-display")
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YmEZz/), for other relative methods, you want [the tree traversal section of the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: Ok, the complete line would be: $(this).find("a.link").attr("data-display"); ?

Comment: Also tested and working, so both answers work perfectly, thanks again Nick (you have saved me 2 times this week), but today you'll share credit with Anton N.